# How to Rewrite a URL with an Id and text using htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Actually I don't know the regex etc and I want to rewrite URL using .htacess. I have the Following URL

```
http://www.example.com/post.php?post_id=114&post_txt=this-should-not-happen-again
```

I want to rewrite it like this

```
http://www.example.com/114/this-should-not-happen-again
```

What Should I write in .htaccess file to achieve my target?

Comment: Please clarify: I assume you want the url that's in the browser bar to be this one: `http://www.example.com/114/this-should-not-happen-again` ?

Comment: @goodeye You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:
It looks for digits, slash, any-characters. It inserts the digits in the `$1`, and the any-characters in `$2`.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(.+)$ /post.php?post_id=$1&post_txt=$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /post.php?post_id=$1&post_txt=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I think this inverts what the OP wants. You're rewriting his desired outcome to his original request.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/post.php?post_id=(\d+)&post_txt=(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Also, a very similar question exists on superuser [here](https://superuser.com/questions/155139/htaccess-301-redirect-with-regular-expressions)